# Как поставить стрелки (слайдер) по бокам баннера?

Tags: html, css, slider, слайдер

Нужно поставить стрелки справа и слева посередине баннера, но они находится под баннером[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Делал без JS

Код:

HTML:

```
        <nav class="navbar">
            <div class="container">
                <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Город мастеров</a>
                <div class="navbar-wrap">
    
                    <ul class="navbar-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">О нас</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Портфолио</a></li>
                        <li><a href="C:/Users/Denis/Desktop/Site/catalog/catalog.html">Каталог</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    
                </div>
                <p class="numberphone"> 8 (383) 375-20-55 <span class="hour">c 9 – 18 </span></p>
                <a href="#" class="callback">Записаться на замер</a>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div class="all">
            <input checked type="radio" name="respond" id="desktop">
                <article id="slider">
                    <input checked type="radio" name="slider" id="switch1">
                    <input type="radio" name="slider" id="switch2">
                    <div id="slides">
                        <div id="overflow">
                            <div class="image">
                                <article>
                                    <section id="main_banner">
                                        <div class="container">
                                            <div class="inner_banner">
                                                <h1>Мы снизили цены!<br>Спешите оформить<br>заказ прямо сейчас!</h1>
                                                <a href="#" class="btn btn_next">Узнать подробнее</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </section>
                                </article>
                                <article>
                                    <section id="main_banner">
                                        <div class="container">
                                            <div class="inner_banner">
                                                <h1>Мы снизили цены!<br>Спешите оформить<br>заказ прямо сейчас!</h1>
                                                <a href="#" class="btn btn_next">Узнать подробнее</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </section>
                                </article>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="controls">
                        <label for="switch1"></label>
                        <label for="switch2"></label>
                    </div>
                </article>
        </div>
    </body>
```

CSS:

````
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}
.navbar .container {
  height: inherit;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
.navbar-menu {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;

}
.navbar-menu li {
  display: inline-block;

}
.navbar-menu li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #000;
  opacity: 0.6;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px;
  
  transition: all .07s ease-in-out;
}
.navbar-menu li a:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
.navbar-wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  
}
.callback {
  margin-left: 20px;
  padding: 12px 40px;
  background-color: coral;
  border-radius: 100px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all .1s ease-out;
}
.callback:hover {
  transform: scale(1.04);
  color: #fff;
}
.navbar-brand {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 26px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;

}
.navbar-brand:hover {
  color: coral;
  transition: all .10s ease-in-out;
}
.numberphone {
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-top: 17px;
  
}
body {
  position: relative;
  font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.4;
  color: #000;
  min-width: 320px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: auto;
}
#main_banner {
  padding: 95px 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: bottom right;
  background-image: url(banner.png);
  position: relative;
}
#main_banner .inner_banner >h1{
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 57px;
  font-weight: 600;
  min-width: 838px;
  line-height: 60px;
}
#main_banner .inner_banner >.btn{
  padding: 9px 15px;
  font-size: 24px;
}
.btn {
  font-style: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: 9px 24px;
  background-color: #000;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition: all .4s ease;
  -o-transition: all .4s ease;
  transition: all .4s ease;
}
.btn:hover {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #000;
}
.btn.btn_next {
  background-color: rgb(255, 129, 25);
}
.btn.btn_next:hover {
  background-color:rgb(255, 104, 49);
}
.container {
  width: 85%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


#slider{ 
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#slides article{ 
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
}

#slides .image{ 
  width: 500%;
  line-height: 0;
  position: relative;
}

#overflow{ 
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

article img{ 
  width: 100%;
}

#desktop:checked ~ #slider{
  max-width: 1920px; 
}


#switch1:checked ~ #controls label:nth-child(5), 
#switch2:checked ~ #controls label:nth-child(1),
#switch5:checked ~ #controls label:nth-child(4){
  background: url('prev.png') no-repeat; 
  float: left;
  display: block;
  height: 68px;
  width: 68px;
  margin-bottom: 300px;
  position: absolute;
}


#switch1:checked ~ #controls label:nth-child(2), 
#switch2:checked ~ #controls label:nth-child(3),
#switch5:checked ~ #controls label:nth-child(1){
  background: url('next.png') no-repeat; 
  float: right;
  margin-bottom: 300px;
  display: block;
  height: 68px;
  width: 68px;
  position: absolute;
}
label, a{ 
  cursor: pointer;
}

.all input{ 
  display: none;
}


#switch1:checked ~ #slides .image{
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: -25%;
}

#switch2:checked ~ #slides .image{
  margin-left: -100%;
  margin-bottom: -25%;
}
#slides {
  position: relative;
}


#active label{ 
  border-radius: 10px; 
  display: inline-block; 
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background: #bbb;
}
#controls{ 
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}
#active label:hover{ 
  background: #76c8ff;
  border-color: #777 !important; 
}


#switch1:checked ~ #active label:nth-child(1),
#switch2:checked ~ #active label:nth-child(2),
#switch3:checked ~ #active label:nth-child(3),
#switch4:checked ~ #active label:nth-child(4),
#switch5:checked ~ #active label:nth-child(5){
  background: #18a3dd;
  border-color: #18a3dd !important;
}

#slides .image{ 
  transition: all 800ms cubic-bezier(0.770, 0.000, 0.175, 1.000);
  
}
.image {
  position: relative;
}

#controls label:hover{ 
  opacity: 0.6;
}

#controls label{ 
  transition: opacity 0.2s ease-out;
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

Используйте абсолютное позиционирование (position):

```css
#slider {
  position: relative;
}

#controls label[for="switch1"],
#controls label[for="switch2"] {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

#controls label[for="switch1"] {
  left: 0;
}

#controls label[for="switch2"] {
  right: 0;
}
```